# Spring Boot Microservice Connecting to Kafka

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a Kafka consumer defined in my microservice. I have deployed 5 instances of my application. I have set concurrency parameter in ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory to 2. Does this mean there are 2 consumer instances for each app instance or 2 consumer instances for the entire topic that I am connecting to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you have 2 consumers in each app instance; you need at least 10 partitions on the topic so each consumer will be assigned a partition. The app instances don't know about each other.

Comment: Thanks Gary! I did a test by setting the concurrency to 5. I have 2 app instances and 10 partitions. But I see only 5 consumers. I repeated the test with 4 ,3 ,2 and 1. Each  time I see only the number of instances sent in concurrent parameter. Does it not mean that it getting applied at the topic level?

Comment: It should work as I described; assuming you are using broker group management, you should see log messages about partitions being assigned as each instance starts. You can't do your own assignment if you want the partitions distributed across the instances.

Comment: Thanks  Gary , could this be a rebalancing issue? I am now assuming when the first app starts , all 10 partitions are being assigned to 5 instances from first app that becomes active. I am guess the second app is not listening to any partitions, Is there a way to force rebalance using any kafka command?

Comment: The rebalance will occur automatically.

Comment: Thanks Gary. Are there any parameters that govern rebalancing?

Comment: There's a new setting in the [0.11.0.0 client](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#upgrade_1100_notable), but that's to delay the rebalance while instances are coming online. We're working on adding support for the 0.11.0.0 client. If you are not seeing rebalancing happening; I suggest you turn on DEBUG logging on both instances to see what's happening.

Comment: Thanks Gary for your help !